# How to get all documents in a group, team and spaces and bulk download them using Jive rest API and CURL?

Tags: curl, jive

I'm new to Jive and currently in the process of migrating content from jive. I see documents uploaded in teams, groups and subspaces. I can't find a way to download document in bulk through the UI. Downloading manually each document going to each of the teams/groups is going to take lot of time. I see jive supports REST API, however I'm unable to figure out how to do get call to retrieve all the teams/groups, then get all documents in each of the teams/groups and then loop through the list to call the content service to download them. I've tried using Curl calling the content api to download a single file like this. https://example.jive.com/api/core/v3/contents/documentid/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all the places use the following:

```
GET /api/core/v3/places
```

You can then filter based on the place type (e.g. space, group, etc). Once all the places are retrieved, use the the endpoint below to retrieve all the content that belongs to that place:

```
GET /api/core/v3/places/{placeId}/contents
```

You can also filter on multiple aspects. This response has a lot of details on the content. You find more details on the [API documentation](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/index.html).

You can also execute requests in batch with the endpoint below as documented [here](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/BatchService.html):

```
POST /executeBatch
```

For the example above the following request could be used to retrieve all places and the content from all those places:

```
[
     {
         "key": "places",
         "request": {
             "method": "GET",
             "endpoint": "/api/core/v3/places"
         }
     }, {
         "key": "content",
         "request": {
             "method": "GET",
             "endpoint": "${places:$.list[*].resources.contents.ref}"
         }
     }
]
```

Comment: Many thanks. I did the get request /api/core/v3/places and it returns me an array list of places in the format - "list" : [ {
    "id" : "1094",
    "resources" : {
    }
}
]

The id that is referred above apparently is not the place id, but I've been given those ids as group ids. The actual group id is within the resources.contents.ref url as you mentioned. I would like to query the places end point with that id. I tried this but that didn't work

/api/core/v3/places?filter=type(group)&filter=id(1094)

Any idea how I can query places end point with id in places:$.list[*].id?

Comment: Also the get call returns only 25 results and I need to make subsequent calls. Is there a way to automate this using the batch request?

Comment: You can use the regular Group ID (not Place ID) in the filter for groups as "filter=entityDescriptor(700,GROUP_ID)".

Comment: You can increase the number of results using the count param in the request but the limit is 100. You could make subsequent batch requests while results are returned.

Comment: Many thanks Andre.The entityDescriptor filter worked fine.Using batch request would it be possible to make a Get request to the contents.ref url and download all the files referred in binaryURL of the contents request?I've tried making a request using CURL passing in json data as per the example you provided above.However I get url malformed error. 
curl -i -u username:pwd -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST /executeBatch -d "@contents.json" https://example.jive.com
End point is on https. If you could pls share a curl example for making a batch request.

Comment: You might be better off using a tool like Postman to validate these requests as curl can be confusing for more complex requests. The request should also against "JIVE_URL/api/core/v3/executeBatch", not just "/executeBatch".

Comment: Many thanks Andre. Curl command worked fine after correcting the executeBatch path. I had tried the Postman but had issues connecting to the API. For downloading the document I use the url in the binaryURL property /contents/id/data. However I see not all documents have this binaryURL property nor attachments. Is it possible to download documents using the /docs/DOC-ID value?

Comment: The /data endpoint is available for binaries and the "binaryURL" attribute is available for Files (which is a special version of Document). You need use the "content.text" attribute of the documents to get their content. There is no dedicated endpoint for documents in the API, just the generic content endpoints.